# Black screen after update

Tags: release-loki

Like a number of users, I have a black screen after updating last month. I have tried a few possible solutions on stackexhange, unfortunately, none worked. If anyone is willing to help, I'd appreciate  it. Just tell me what information you may need from me.

If I can't avoid a reboot, I would like to back up the HHD. Any advice to do this through terminal?

Comment: Please add more information about your system. I would also like to know when the problem occurs, after logging in? or is there any login screen at all?

Comment: Hasan, thank you for your reply. I can see the log in screen, the accounts and area to type the passwords. Apart from that, the screen is black (cant see the wallpaper, etc). Interestingly, I can find the poweroff menu in the top right corner, which also pops up normally. Everything else is black. If I try to log in, the screen goes totally black and after a minute or two, returns to the log in screen. I have a hunch that its related to the graphics drivers, but I have not been able to update the drivers through terminal (or remove the old drivers, then install the new one(430)). Basic system

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. If you still have the problem, can you please confirm whether you changed any configuration of your user account?, the account you are trying to login with.

Comment: No problem. I did not make any changes. Just ran the updates through the software centre, restarted and ended up with the black screen.

Answer (score 0):

I decided that it was simpler to reset than continue trying to find a solution. Luckily, I was able to back up my files beforehand.

Mods, feel free to lock this thread if necessary.